# Displaying distance on the screen of an android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a GPSActivity class that basically calculates the total distance traveled every time the location is updated. My problem is I want to be able to display the distance traveled on the screen in another activity and update the display to the new distance when the distance changes. I looked around but couldn't find a useful answer. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Use a static variable and access it in another activity and set it and show it in a toast.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't indicated if this "other activity" is active at the time. If it's not, you need to rethink how you go about things.

It sounds like your GPSActivity class should be a service, not an activity. This service can be started any of a number of ways so that it can collect its data. Your activity (which should only be used when a UI is needed) can attach to your service when it wishes to get an update. If you want the service to drive updates then your service can broadcast when it has an update, and your activity can create a broadcast listener to receive them.

Research on broadcasts and services will make it simple to learn more about these Android concepts.

Comment: This doesnt seem constructive to the question.

Comment: My problem is "Displaying" the changed distance on the screen. And as the distance changes I want to update the "display" on the screen

Comment: @Mazen -- your problem is very easily solved using the tools I've described. If you don't see that then perhaps you should show what you've tried and mention what failed.

Answer (score -1):

You should store the Distance variable inside of SharePreference like this.

TO pull out the Distance in ALL activities.

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("distance", 0);
  int distance = settings.getInt("distance", 0); //or String settings.getString();
```

To put the distance inside the shared preference this is how..

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("distance", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("distance", distance); // or editor.putString()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: inside your GPSActivity class just put the Distance variable in shared preference and it will be availible to all activities.

Comment: In my opinion, storing temporal data to the disk is very wasteful and unnecessary.

Comment: Its not that wasteful actually. This is the best way to what seems to be his problem. If you have a better way please let us know.

Comment: My problem is "Displaying" the changed distance on the screen. And as the distance changes I want to update the "display" on the screen

Comment: This should help you out http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html